# Magento 2: Sort Product collection by Last update Product

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I am trying to fetch product collection based on crated custom attribute that is **is_home_page.**

Check by below code.

```
echo "<pre>";
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('show_on_home_page',['eq'=>'1'])
->setPageSize(4)
->setOrder('sort_order','DESC')
->load();
```

So, here what i need is Currently i want to display products on home page which product has attribute set to **Yes**.

I can able to get collection of products which has attribute Yes.

But i would like to get collection in order to last updated product.

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do for you

```
 $productCollection->addAttributeToSort('update_at', 'DESC')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC')
```

instead of

```
->setOrder('sort_order','DESC')
```

Comment: we do have feature in manual sort & automatic sort in EE how we need to fetch   products by manual sort? https://prnt.sc/xothut please advise